On the proof of Kuratowski's Theorem
I was reading the proof of Kuratowski's theorem in  Prasolov's Elements of Combinatorial and Differential Topology and there's one claim I did not understand. The proof is divided into three steps and he starts off assuming that there exist nonplanar graphs without subgraphs homeomorphic to $K_{3,3}$ and $K_{5}$, and taking $G$ to be, among all such graphs, the one with minimum number of edges. Later on, during Step 2, he writes
"Since the graph $G$ is minimal, it has no vertices incident to fewer than three edges".
I can't see why this is the case. Any help would be appreciated.

If a vertex has degree 1, it can be deleted. The new graph is still non-planar. If a vertex has degree $2$, we can apply the smoothing operation.

Correct , @kabenyuk , Degree Zero will be deleted too.

@kabenyuk Thanks!
